# Form submit with a file in Spring mvc + bootstrap

Tags: spring, twitter-bootstrap, spring-mvc, file-upload

Its a two part question.
I am trying to submit a pop up form with a file and textarea. I am not able to receive file in my controller code.

Part 1 - How do I receive the file at the controller.

Part 2 - Once I submit the form, how do I close the popup and remain on the same page so that URL does not change.

Popup code-

```
<form name="eperform">
    <div class="modal fade" id="export" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog">
            <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove" aria-hidden="true" style="padding-top: 10px;"></span>
                    </button>
                    <h4 class="modal-title custom_align" id="Heading">Provide ID's here:</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <div>
                        <fieldset style="margin-left: 10px;">
                            <legend style="font-size: medium;">File Upload</legend>                         
                            <input id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload" type="file" style="margin-left: 20px"/>
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                    <br/>
                    <div>
                        <fieldset style="margin-left: 10px;">
                            <legend style="font-size: medium;">Ids</legend>
                            <label for="envIds"></label> 
                            <textarea class="form-control noresize" rows="4" style="width:98% " name="ids" id="ids" value="">
                            </textarea>
                            <input type="hidden" id="server" name="server" value="${server}">
                            <input type="hidden" id="port" name="port" value="${port}"> 
                            <input type="hidden" id="queuename1" name='queuename1' value="">
                            <input type="hidden" id="environment" name="environment" value="${environment}">
                        </fieldset>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer ">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" id="eid"
                        onclick="exportObjects(document.getElementById('ids').value,document.getElementById('queuename1').value,'${port}','${server}','${environment}',document.getElementById('fileUpload').value)">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></span>Export
                    </button>
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">
                        <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span> Cancel
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

Javascript code-

```
function exportObjects(ids, queueName, port, server, environment, fileUpload) {
    var strHREF = "/exportObjects?ids=" + ids
            + "&queueName=" + queueName + "&port=" + port + "&server="
            + server + "&environment=" + environment +"&fileUpload=" + fileUpload;
    document.eperform.action = strHREF;
    document.eperform.submit();
}
```

Controller code-

```
@RequestMapping(value="/exportObjects", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView exportObjects(HttpServletRequest request) throws Exception{
    String server =request.getParameter("server");
    String port =request.getParameter("port");
    String environment = request.getParameter("environment");
    String type =request.getParameter("queueName");
    String ids = request.getParameter("ids");
    CommonsMultipartFile file = (CommonsMultipartFile) request.getAttribute("fileUpload");

    if(file != null && file.getSize() != 0){
        String path=request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/");
        String filename=file.getOriginalFilename();
        System.out.println(path+" "+filename);  
        try{  
            InputStream in = file.getInputStream();
            BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(in));
            StringBuilder out = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
                out.append(line);
            }
            System.out.println(out.toString());

        }catch(Exception e){System.out.println(e);} 
    }

    // Perform action on ids and file data

    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    // I do not know what to do here.
    return model;
}
```

Comment: To increase the chances of receiving an answer, post only the relevant parts of the code. It seems like you've tried to solve everything at once instead of just figuring out how to get a file to upload.

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you are not familiar with web developement,I recommend you take some time to review the java web development knowledge.

Below are the answer for your two questions:

- If you want to upload a file to the server,you must add **enctype="multipart/form-data"** to your form

  ```html
  <form name="eperform" enctype="multipart/form-data">
       <div>
          <fieldset style="margin-left: 10px;">
               <legend style="font-size: medium;">File Upload</legend>                         
               <input id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload" type="file" style="margin-left: 20px"/>
                      </fieldset>
       </div>
  </form>
  ```

  - If you want to stay on the same page,you should using an **asynchronous** method to submit your action,and **[Ajax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming))** is your best choice.You need to submit your request and in the *success* callback method close the popup dialog.

  ```
  $.ajax({
      url:"exportObjects",
      type:"post",
      data:{
         queueName:queueName,
         port:port,
         server:server,
         environment:environment
      },
      success:function(data){
          //if the request submit success,invoke 'close' method to close the dialog
         $("#dialog_div").dialog("close");
      }
  });
  ```

  In your [springmvc](/questions/tagged/springmvc) code,you should not use *ModelAndView* because it will forward to a new page,you need to return an original string,like the code listed below,after that you can use **[MultipartFile](http://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/web/multipart/MultipartFile.html)** to get your upload file:

  ```java
   @RequestMapping(value="eperform",method=RequestMethod.POST)
   @ResponseBody
   public String updateNodeRelation(@RequestParam(value="fileUpload")
                MultipartFile file,HttpServletRequest request) {
                 System.out.println(file.getOriginalFilename());
                 return "success";
    }
  ```

  **UPDATED**
- If you want to submit a file and then stay on the same page,then you need to use iframe and not use **Ajax**,as below:

  ```java
  <!-- using iframe to stay on the same page-->
  <form id="eperform"name="eperform" action="exportObjects" enctype="multipart/form-data"
      target="hidden_frame">
       <div>
          <fieldset style="margin-left: 10px;">
               <legend style="font-size: medium;">File Upload</legend>                         
               <input id="fileUpload" name="fileUpload" type="file" 
                      style="margin-left: 20px"/>
                      </fieldset>
       </div>
       <iframe id="hidden_frame"  name="hidden_frame" 
                  style="display:none"/>
       <button type="button" onclick="submitFile()">Submit</button>
  </form>
  ```

  And using the below **Javascript** code to submit the form and close popup dialog**

  ```javascript
  function submitFile(){
       $("#eperform").submit();
       $("#dialog_div").dialog("close");
  }
  ```

Comment: request never goes to method if I write value="eperform" and If I write it as "exportObjects" then it gives error.

Comment: @RahulGodara I just updated my answer,you can check my updated solution